# Android Fragment. AsyncTask

Tags: android

Я вызываю `AsyncTask` в фрагменте. Все этапы прохожу нормально, но в методе `onPostExecute()` мне нужно заполнить `TextView`. Вот код фрагмента:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_fragment, container, false);
    tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewFIO);
    tv.setText("TEXT");
    new GetUserInformation(getActivity(), "zz@zz");
    setTextTV("ADSDADAD");
    return v;
}
```

И сам onPostExecute():

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    tv.setText(otvet)
}
```

При этом ответ не равен null. Мне нужно заполнить `TextView`. Как быть?

Comment: Так а в чём проблема?

Comment: @temq, проблема в том, что текст все равно не изменяется, хотя так реализовывал в активити и норм.

Comment: Ну значит не так реализовали как в активити, приложите полный код асинк таска. Сейчас, судя по вашему ```onPostExecute```, в textview у вас должен отобразиться ```otvet``` если он действительно приходит. TextView то находится во фрагменте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужно передать какой нибудь колбэк в `AsyncTask` и дернуть метод этого колбэка в методе `onPostExecute`

```
public interface Callback{
     onPostExecute(String result);
}
```

---

```
new GetUserInformation(getActivity(), "zz@zz", new CallBack(){
     onPostExecute(String result){
          tv.setText(result)
     }
});
```

---

**GetUserInformation:**

```
private Callback callback; 

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    callback.onPostExecute(result);
}
```